# Confusion in relating conservation of momentum and conservation of energy in a system of particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, momentum

Here I have a numerical which caused me confusion , a bullet is fired with a certain velocity horizontally towards a block of the same mass kept on a horizontal surface which is not frictionless , here friction is non impulsive so momentum is conserved just before the block starts moving after the collision, if I use the conservation of energy between the block and the bullet because there is not net external force on the system , and the normal recation between them is a conservative force so the total energy should be conserved

$$\rm Initial~kinetic~energy=\frac1 2 (mass ~of ~bullet)(velocity ~squared)$$

$$\rm =final ~kinetic ~energy ~just ~before ~friction~ starts ~to~ act$$

So if we calculate the velocity of the block here we get that it is 1 by √2 times the velocity of the bullet initially and both the block and bullet now move with the same velocity at all instants

But now if we consider the conservation of momentum as no net external force acts on the system , I find that the common velocity is half the initial velocity and in this case the final kinetic energy is one fourth of the initial kinetic energy , and due to this I am getting different answers from these two methods , please clarify where is the mistake and please explain the relation between momentum conservation and energy conservation in a system of particles where no external force acts

Comment: I find your first paragraph (a single run on sentence) confusing. For conservation of momentum questions it is important to define the system. What exactly is the system here?

Comment: The system here considered is the bullet and block system

Comment: In that case momentum is not conserved because the friction force exerted by the surface on the block is an external force on the system.

Comment: Kinetic energy isn't conserved in inelastic collisions. Consider what happens to all the energy when a car drives into a immovable brick wall.

Answer (score 0):

If the bullet sticks in the block mechanical energy is not conserved. The collision is completely inelastic . So only momentum is conserved. But "surface which is not frictionless " says also energy and momentum before the impact is not conserved. So this seems strange , also "friction is non impulsive "  is strange.

Comment: The question here actually says that the bullet velocity is say 'u' and the coefficient of friction is mew , and it is required to find the distance travelled by the block and bullet before they come to rest , how do I solve it then?

Answer (score 0):

The bullet takes time to slow down as does the block to speed up.

During the time the bullet is slowing down and the block is speeding up there is relative motion between them, frictional forces are acting and heat is generated.

Sound will be generated by this will not be a significant amount of energy compared with the initial kinetic energy of the bullet.

The bullet will also do work permanently breaking bonds between the molecules which make up the block; the bullet makes a hole in the block.
Breaking bonds requires energy and this comes from the kinetic energy of the bullet.

Thus overall the amount of kinetic energy the system (bullet and block) has decreases.

Answer (score 0):

> so momentum is conserved just before the block starts moving

If the system is the bullet and block, as you stated in comments, then the static friction force exerted on the block by the surface prior to becoming kinetic friction when the block moves is an external force on the system, and momentum is not conserved. If the bullet, block, and surface (fixed to the Earth) is the system, then momentum is conserved both before and after the block moves.

> ...after the collision, if I use the conservation of energy between
> the block and the bullet because there is not net external force on
> the system

You did not state whether or not the bullet becomes embedded in or causes permanent deformation of the block during the collision.  Although overall energy (including internal energy and heat) is always conserved, mechanical energy (KE and PE of motion and position of the object as a whole) is not conserved if the collision between the bullet and block is inelastic, as would be the case if the bullet were embedded in or otherwise results in inelastic deformation of the block.

> and the normal reaction between them is a conservative force so the
> total energy should be conserved

Don't know what you mean by "normal reaction", but the equation you provided does not account for the energy dissipated due to the inelastic collision between the bullet and the block.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes thanks I totally didn't realise that mechanical energy shouldn't be conserved in inelastic collision , as the bullet is embedded in the block here

Answer (score -1):

*"if I use the conservation of energy between the block and the bullet because there is not net external force on the system"*

This principle is wrong. Internal forces can change energy.

Factor this problem into two problems:

1. what is the final velocity, $v$, of the bullet/block system?
2. how far does a bullet/block system going $v$ slide on a surface with friction?

On (1), if you want to conceptualize internal energy...just have an ideal spring catch the bullet, and latch it when the bullet/block have the same velocity: how much energy is in the spring?

Also: try to explain the problem more clearly...it might help.

Comment: Please explain how can internal forces change the total mechanical energy

Comment: The "internal" force deforms the block, making a hole needs energy most of it go to heat. Imagine hammering the bullet in the block than you feel your loss of energy

Comment: So in conclusion, whenever internal forces are spring force , coulomb force or some other conservative forces , we can conserve mechanical energy whenever a collision is not involved , is this right?

Comment: @ChemistLegend In the real world: mechanic deformation -> heat, sound. The point of the idealized spring is that the system is mechanically deformed in one degree of freedom, that is a higher potential energy state, vs. irl, where there are $N_A$ (or more) degrees of freedom that aren't really addressed by introductory mechanics.

Comment: @ChemistLegend "Please explain how can internal forces change the total mechanical energy" Internal forces can change total mechanical energy if they are dissipative, such as  kinetic friction and inelastic deformation associated with inelastic collisions.  Internal conservative forces (elastic, electrostatic, gravitational, etc.) don't change total mechanical energy. On the other hand, ALL external forces (conservative or not) can change total mechanical energy